# Service weighting with Traefik 2.2 using native Kubernetes Ingress objects

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

We use native Kubernetes Ingress API objects along with Traefik 1.7 supported annotations to split traffic between main and canary deployments in our on-premises cluster.

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-weights: |-
      our-service: 100%
      our-canary-service: 0%
```

These values are updated incrementally giving increasing weight to the canary during a deployment of a new image version. Once the canary deployment is successfully fielding traffic at a predefined weighting limit we update the image of the main deployment and revert the weighting.

**Is this workflow possible using Traefik 2.2?**

We have run up a test traefik 2.2 installation using a specified Ingress Class annotation but we can't figure out a way to do service weighting using native Ingress objects. Is Weighted Round Robin (WRR) the only way to get a similar workflow with v2.2? WRR seems to require transitioning away from Ingress objects to Traefik's own IngressRoute resources.

So the question is:

What mechanism should we employ to do weighted service splitting to support a canary deployment workflow using Traefik 2.2 and native Ingress objects?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [traefikservice](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-traefikservice%5D%28https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-traefikservice) CRD? This is now introduced as suggested way to do the loadbalancing in traefik requested by the community in order to have less annotations.

It seems that in version 2.1 they introduced service weighting using  [traefikservice](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-traefikservice%5D%28https://docs.traefik.io/v2.1/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-traefikservice) CRD to addresss community concerns to use the features without to many annotations:

> However, as the community expressed the need to benefit from Traefik
> features without resorting to (lots of) annotations, we ended up
> writing a [Custom Resource
> Definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/)
> (alias CRD in the following) for an IngressRoute type, defined below,
> in order to provide a better way to configure access to a Kubernetes
> cluster.

If you care to look on this [github](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4494#issuecomment-557086356)  issues, it appears that they suggested this solution to address the issues with weighting in version 1.7.  I`d suggest to open an request on github to check the possibility of your request.

Comment: Thanks, but we have many native Ingress objects and are loath to translate all of them to non native resources. Annotations are trivial to add with Kustomize and even easier to modify with `kubectl patch ingress`.